# Why is the DataItem property null for this DataGridItem here?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, asp.net-2.0

## Problem

I have a `ButtonColumn` to edit a row defined like this:

```
<asp:ButtonColumn DataTextField="job_code" ButtonType="LinkButton" HeaderText="Job Code"
    CommandName="edit"></asp:ButtonColumn>
```

and in the `OnItemCommand` handler for the `DataGrid` I have this code:

```
If e.CommandName = "edit" Then
    Dim o As ListDataModel = CType(e.Item.DataItem, ListDataModel)
    If o Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ...
End If
```

**but `e.Item.DataItem` is `null` here.**

*I've looked through the related questions and verified the following:*

1. The `ItemType` of `e.Item` is set to `ListItemType.Item` and therefore should be allowed to house the `DataItem`. This also jives with the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagriditem.dataitem.aspx).
2. I leveraged data binding **-see the code section below.**
3. I have set the `DataKeyField` attribute on the `asp:DataGrid` like this: `DataKeyField="job_code"`.

## Data Binding Code (happens in the Search method)

```
Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Dim list As List(Of ListDataModel) = New List(Of ListDataModel)

    While reader.Read()
        list.Add(New ListDataModel With
                 {
                     ...
                 })
    End While

    dgSearchResults.DataSource = list
    dgSearchResults.DataBind()
End Using
```

Now, the `Search` method is an `onserverclick` event handler for an `input` button. The flow would be for the user to search for the results and then click on one of the command button to edit the row, **therefore the `Search` method would not be run when the `OnItemCommand` handler was fired.**

Comment: `DataItem` is always `Nothing` on postbacks. ASP.NET stores the values in `ViewState`(if enabled).

Comment: @TimSchmelter, so it will never have a value when the user clicks on the edit `ButtonColumn` then?

Comment: No, only if the grid is databound, but you can use the `CommandArgument` to get the ID.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, thanks for your help man. It lead me to a solution -convoluted though -I posted it as an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so the resolution for this ended up a bit convoluted. First I ended up having to store the search result set in `Session`, so I built a `Dictionary` for that:

```
Dim cache As Dictionary(Of String, ListDataModel) = New Dictionary(Of String, ListDataModel)
```

and added to that `Dictionary` when building the `ListDataModel` objects. Then, in the `OnItemCommand` handler I ended up having the use `Reflection` like this:

```
Dim cache As Dictionary(Of String, ListDataModel) = CType(Session("SearchResults"), Dictionary(Of String, ListDataModel))
If cache Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim prop As PropertyInfo = e.CommandSource.GetType().GetProperty("Text")
If prop Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim o As ListDataModel = cache(prop.GetValue(e.CommandSource, Nothing).ToString())
If o Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

As you can see I first pulled the "SearchResults" out of `Session`, then tried to get at the `Text` property of the `DataGridLinkButton`. I had to use `Reflection` because the `DataGridLinkButton` class isn't visible. Then finally, if I found the property, I pulled off the value.

Though this works, and I hope that my solution is a by-product of something else weird in the application I'm maintaining, it's really not what I wanted to do in the end. This is a pretty poor interface to the `DataGrid` -**but it is ASP.NET 2.0 and so it's some old stuff!**